# m2m_change signal not work form admin site but work from shell

Tags: django, django-admin, django-signals, django-shell

I have a model

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=45, blank=False, null=False)
    perants= models.ManyToManyField('self',through="CategoryParent",symmetrical=False,blank=True)
```

and the `CatigoryPerants` is :

```
class CategoryParent(models.Model):
    chiled_filed=models.ForeignKey("Catigory", on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="parent_of_category",blank=False)
    parent_filed=models.ForeignKey("Catigory", on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=False)
```

and  I try to run a signal in signal.py:

```
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Catigory.perants.through )
def CatigoryParentSignals(sender, instance, action, pk_set, **kwargs):
    print("Some text or throw Validation Expiation or doin any thing")
```

The problem is when I add new parent to the `Category` from Shell with `.parents.set([parents])` or`.parants.add(parent)` its work but when add any parent from admin site this signal isn't work

I add the `signal.py` in `ready` function `apps.py`

```
class myappConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'myapp'
    def ready(self) -> None:
        import myapp.signals
        return super().ready()
```

and then add `myappConfig` to the `__init__.py` `defult_app_config`

Comment: How are you connecting the signal when your app starts? The signal.py module will not be loaded unless done explicitly

Comment: I add the details to the question